# How to get node content in an sql query?

Tags: nodes, database

I see that in D6 the node table has only the title of the node. How to query database to get  the body (content) of a particular node?

Update: I figured out the content bodies are stored in node_revisions table.

Comment: Are you asking this so as to be able to get this information from an external non-Drupal application?

Answer (score 5):

**Drupal 7**

In Drupal 7 body content is saved in `field_data_body` and `field_revision_body` tables.

So example query to fetch title and body would be:

```
SELECT title, r.body_value, n.changed FROM node n LEFT JOIN field_data_body r ON n.nid = r.entity_id AND n.vid = r.revision_id
```

To query via drush, run `drush sqlq` following by above query.

Comment: Give this man a beer.

Answer (score 3):

For education purposes, this is the sql that D6 Views produces (according to its sql preview):

This particular node would be the one having node id 1:

```
SELECT node_revisions.body AS node_revisions_body,
       node_revisions.format AS node_revisions_format
FROM node node
LEFT JOIN node_revisions node_revisions 
ON node.vid = node_revisions.vid 
WHERE node.nid = 1
```

In a module, however, you should use proper methods such as db_query() for maintainability and security.